# How can I type alias multiple Kotlin types into a single type

Tags: android, kotlin, type-alias

Suppose I have variable which can be Int, String or Float. I want to create a generic type using type alias that includes all the above 3 types. Something like

typealias customType = Int || String || Float

Comment: limiting it to only those 3 types is unfortunately not possible. You might be able to work with `Any` but that allows using other types as well

Comment: @IvoBeckers you could perhaps get away with using a custom setter in combination with `Any?` as datatype, if a type doesn't fall withing these types you could set it to null, but i suppose that's a bit of a hack, also probably depends on what OP is trying to do

Comment: There are no union types in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your comment to previous answer:

Unfortunately, Kotlin **does not** support multiple generic constraints and union types currently.

The only way is to use `Any` or inheritance.

```
sealed interface StringOrFloat

data class StringType(val field: String): StringOrFloat

data class FloatType(val field: Float): StringOrFloat

fun mapToStringOrFloat(value: Any): StringOrFloat {
    return when(value) {
        is Float -> FloatType(value),
        is String -> StringType(value)
        else -> ... // you can throw exception here
    }
}

val value: StringOrFloat = mapToStringOrFloat(someValue)
```

Comment: If you make it a sealed interface and drop the `AnyType`, it would make it easier to unpack when you need to work with it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks, it is cleaner indeed since possible `when` expressions will not require else branch. I edited my answer according to your improvement idea

Comment: That needs to be `sealed interface`, not `sealed class`, or else you need to call the super constructor.

Comment: thanks..I guess I could get away with this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any` as the datatype like:

```
private lateinit var value: Any
```

`Any` is superclass of all the datatypes like String, Int, Float etc and in future, you can assign any value to it like:

```
value = "hello"
```

or

```
value = 6
```

or

```
value = 6F
```

Comment: I know "Any" can be used. But I want to fine tune it to be just String/Float. I know this can be done in Typescript, just want to know if similar is available in Kotlin